# Adding stock indicators into a Pandas DataFrame - ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror, stock, technical-indicator

I have a pandas dataframe of stocks with ohlc data and I’m using the btalib (technical analysis) package to add in some indicators. The dataframe I have now is similar to this, but with 200 rows for each stock (QQQ Holdings top 500 stocks).

```
symbol        time    open  ...   close    volume
AAPL    2019-10-28  247.42  ...  249.04  22187260
AAPL    2019-10-29  248.97  ...  243.29  32725739
AAPL    2019-10-30  244.76  ...  243.29  25443913
AAPL    2019-10-31  247.24  ...  248.84  29688327
AAPL    2019-11-01  249.54  ...  255.84  33985331
```

SMA is calculated using stock data from previous days’ closing prices. So if the period I’m using for my SMA is 20 days, the closing prices are (essentially) just averaged for the last 20 days, as shown below

```
sma20 = btalib.sma(df, period=20) # instantiate sma20 w/ period of 20 days
```

However, I have 200 days of data for each stock (as I’ll use a period of 200 for a separate column value later), and **I need the SMA calculation to reset each time the symbol column in the dataframe changes**. This is the part I'm having trouble with.

Here's how it *should* work

`df['sma20'] = sma20.df`

`print(df[200:203])`

output:

The first 20 rows of sma20 are null as they are needed to calculate the values. This part works as intended. However, when the stock symbol switches from AAPL to ADBE, the value for sma20 carries on with the previous 20 records in the dataframe, which are AAPL's records. I need them to reset at this point.

```
record# symbol        time     open  ...    volume    sma20
200     AAPL  2020-08-13  457.720  ...     48325440   412.80320
201     ADBE  2019-10-28  271.580  ...      2002911   407.11320
202     ADBE  2019-10-29  271.680  ...      1483643   401.01470
```

I thought about making my own function for this, but once I add in more complicated indicators this will become very tedious and I feel it's just easier to use a library to help me out.

Here's what I have going right now:

I have a `symbol_shifted` column which essentially just pushes all of the symbols up one place. My idea is that I can check whether symbol is equal to this symbol shifted column. If it's not, then the calculation should reset.

Here's how symbol shifted looks:

```
record# symbol symbol_shifted      sma20
200     AAPL   AAPL            412.80320
201     ADBE   AAPL            407.11320
202     ADBE   ADBE            401.01470
```

And here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
for i in df:
    while True:
        if df['symbol']==df['symbol_shifted']:
            df['sma20']=sma20.df
        else:
            continue
```

I've tried similar logic multiple ways (eg. using the above logic in a function with pandas apply, changing how I index the records), but I cannot seem to get it to work. At record number 201, symbol != symbol_shifted. So when the if statement sees that this is the case, the infinite loop should reset and start the calculation again. I'm not sure why this isn't working but I'd love some feedback or ideas if anyone is willing to provide them! Here's the error I'm currently receiving:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```